# Auto adding rows to prevent overlapping filter data

Tags: google-sheets

I am filtering 5 Columns of data from SHEET2 into SHEET1 so the output from the filter is SHEET1 A1:E1, SHEET1 A2:E2, SHEET1 A3:E3 etc

Eventually the output will reach SHEET1 A10:E10 which is a problem because I already have data on SHEET1 A10:E10.

Is there a filter setting to have rows added automatically to avoid overlapping? Something like "Auto add rows to prevent data overlapping" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add rows based on some rules only with the script. however, in some cases there is possible to run all your formulae under each array. example:

```
={FILTER(...);
  FILTER(...);
  FILTER(...)}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no such function or ability in Google Sheets.